# Fazer trigger executar update depois que a procedure foi executada

Tags: sql, sql-server

gostaria de saber como eu faço no SQL Server para uma trigger verificar se a procedure foi executada e se ela foi executada, essa trigger vai fazer um outro update. Desde já agradeço a atenção.

Att,
Marcilio

Comment: Trigger é só em cima de comando `INSERT` e/ou `DELETE` e/ou `UPDATE`. Não existe trigger em cima de procedure(até porque não faz sentido, é mais fácil só adicionar alguma coisa no fim dela)

Comment: @DH. Entendi, mas na minha trigger eu vou usar o exec.dbo.nomeproc e de pois realizar um update, não é possível realizar isso? Não achei exemplo na Internet

Comment: Detalhe o problema , talvez consigamos modelar uma solução , você está "quase" com uma solução procurando um problema.

Answer (score 1):

Porque o update não é realizado dentro da procedure?

Trigger é uma reação a um comando DDL ou DML.